# JQuery function to control navigation styles (each nav selection a different colour)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm trying to consolidate a function in JQuery which, adds unique colours to each navigational option. In theory I think I should be creating an array and doing perhaps a 'each' function but I keep getting stuck so reverted back to the long-winded way of using JQuery in this instance.

Here is the code;

```
<div id="navigation-container">
<ul class="float-left">
                <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Innovation">Innovation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Our company">Our company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="What we do">What we do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Community">Community</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Newsroom">Newsroom</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the script that I need to compact;

```
$('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(1)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#da032c'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #da032c'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(2)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#0093d0'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #0093d0'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(3)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#000f47'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #000f47'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(4)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#000f47'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #000f47'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(5)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#6d1f7e'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #6d1f7e'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(6)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#b2aa7e'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #b2aa7e'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li:nth-child(7)').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).children().css({'background':'#231f20'});
                    $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':'2px solid #231f20'});
    });
    $('#navigation-container ul li').mouseout(function(){
                    $(this).children().attr({'style':''});
                    $(this).parent().attr({'style':''});
    });
```

The reason why I have to do it like this is because the CMS that the content comes from doesn't allow you to apply a class to each individual 'li' so I have to use JQuery in order to achieve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Desi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','silver','orange','aqua'];
var defaultColor = $('#navigation-container li').eq(0).css('background-color');

$('#navigation-container li').hover(
    function(){
        var thisIndex = $(this).index();
        $(this).css('background-color',colors[thisIndex]);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color',defaultColor);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n28SF/).

---

**Edited** to add the borders, and also style the list as a horizontal 'tab-style' navigation:

```
var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','silver','orange','aqua'];
var defaultColor = $('#navigation-container li').eq(0).css('background-color');

$('#navigation-container li').hover(
    function(){
        var thisIndex = $(this).index();
        $(this).css('background-color',colors[thisIndex]);
        $(this).parent().css('border-bottom-color',colors[thisIndex]);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('background-color',defaultColor);
        $(this).parent().css('border-bottom-color',defaultColor);
    });
```

CSS:

```
#navigation-container ul {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation-container ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}
```

[Revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n28SF/1/).

Comment: @Desi, no problem at all, glad to be of help :)